# problem with storage format of date in mongodb

Tags: datetime, mongodb

I am using mongodb's date type to store date.. I am getting following data from my server's nginx `log [17/Feb/2011:00:07:03 +0000]` it means date is 17/Feb/2011 and time is 00:07:03 and time zone is UTC/GMT. I am using perl's datetime module to format date and store it in mongodb..problem is in mongodb it is storing like this..

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d6c8b2ff991e70412000000"), "date" : "Thu Feb 17 2011 05:37:03 GMT+0530 (IST)" }
```

why it is storing it in IST ..i want the date to be stored as UTC/GMT

my perl code is this

```
use DateTime;
use MongoDB;
use MongoDB::OID;
my $conn = MongoDB::Connection->new(host => 'localhost', port => 27017);
$dt = DateTime->new(
    year       => 2011,
    month      => 2,
    day        => 17, 
    hour       => 00, 
    minute     => 07, 
    second     => 03, 
    time_zone  => 'UTC'
    );  
$conn->testing->logs->insert({"date"=>$dt});
```

Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB/BSON uses UTC timestamps internally.

Either your driver is doing some conversion according to the local time zone or the mongo console. Not sure what you are using here.

Comment: So I mean how to fix it ..i mean what is the problem